# getOrCreateThreadId in API 21

Tags: java, android, mobile, sms

I'm currently developing a fairly basic messaging app targeted towards API level 21. I cannot go higher than that. What is the easiest way to implement a replacement for the `Threads.getOrCreateThreadId` method (which requires API 23) in version 21 (Android 5.0).

Also it is my understanding that the second argument of the method would accept a phone number, am I right in thinking this?

The purpose of this is to be used in a JavaScriptInterface method, as I am using HTML for my layout, as that is much, much easier to work with. I do not want to use APIs that are not visible in the Android SDK, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling, I found [this compatibility class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/ContactsCommon/+/7aba85a08c4729123a55341e8a0f9eb5a89e1a14/src/com/android/contacts/common/compat/TelephonyThreadsCompat.java) which had the functions I needed. I copied two of them, slightly adapting them to my needs. Here they are:

```
private static long getOrCreateThreadIdInternal(Context context, Set<String> recipients) {
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/threadID").buildUpon();
    for (String recipient : recipients) {
        /*if (isEmailAddress(recipient)) {
            recipient = extractAddrSpec(recipient);
        }*/
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("recipient", recipient);
    }
    Uri uri = uriBuilder.build();
    Cursor cursor = query(context.getContentResolver(), uri, new String[] {BaseColumns._ID}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getLong(0);
            } else {
                Log.e("JavaScriptInterface", "getOrCreateThreadId returned no rows!");
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    Log.e("JavaScriptInterface", "getOrCreateThreadId failed with uri " + uri.toString());
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to find or allocate a thread ID.");
}

private static Cursor query(ContentResolver resolver, Uri uri, String[] projection,
                            String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    try {
        return resolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("JavaScriptInterface", "Catch an exception when query: ", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I do not take any credit for this code.